# Query the Pinterest API by keyword or hashtag

Tags: javascript, php, api, pinterest

I've searched the [Pinterest API Documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/) but can't seem to find how to search for pins matching a simple keyword or hashtag.

You can search for **a user's** pins, or all pins that link to a domain, but you can't actually search through Pinterest for pins.

Am I missing something? I would have thought this to be basic functionality.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about how to use a specific API not about code problems

Comment: @charlietfl I kindly request that you don't vote to close. I'm looking for sample code to search for pins on Pinterest. Would you like me to rephrase the question?

Comment: It's not in the documentation because it is not possible. You can search your own Pins, but not the whole codebase.

Comment: This question is old. Any new findings about this issue? I've got the same problem: can't find a way of quering pins by hashtag.